# Candidate-Elimination concept learning algorithm: specialising the general boundary

Tags: machine-learning

I'm reading about concept learning from Mitchell, and I've been looking at the Candidate-Elimination algorithm for identifying a hypothesis to fit a set of training data with binary labels

**The algorithm**

Initialise the 'specific boundary', $S$, as the set of most specific hypotheses. (Initially, this will be $\{<\emptyset, \emptyset,...,\emptyset>\}$, where $\emptyset$ indicates that no value of that attribute indicates a positive classification.)

Initialise the 'general boundary', $G$, as the set of most general hypotheses. (Initially, this will be $\{<?, ?,...,?>\}$, where $?$ indicates that any value of that attribute indicates a positive classification.)

```
for each training instance:
    if label is positive:
        Generalise S
    elif label is negative:
        Specialise G
```

**Example**

Consider the following two instances:

$x_1=<sun, warm, normal, strong, warm, same>, positive$

$x_2 = <sun, warm, high, strong, warm, same>, positive$

$x_3 = <rain, cold, high, strong, warm, change>, negative$

(The first attribute is one of 3 possibilities, the rest are 1 of 2.)

The example can be found on page 33, section 2.5.5 here: https://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/~gabis/ml/ml-books/McGrawHill%20-%20Machine%20Learning%20-Tom%20Mitchell.pdf

So we have

$$S_0=<\emptyset, \emptyset, \emptyset, \emptyset, \emptyset, \emptyset >$$

$$G_0=<?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?>$$

The first instance is positive, so we want to generalise the specific boundary and leave the general boundary. So $$S_1=<sun, warm, normal, strong, warm, same>$$ $$G_1=<?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?>$$ This makes sense to me. The second example is also positive, so we repeat this again: $$S_2=<sun, warm, ?, strong, warm, same>$$ $$G_2=<?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?>$$ This also makes sense to me.

The next part (when we approach a negative instance) is what I'm struggling to understand and need help with. We have a negative instance, so we leave $S_2$ unchanged, but we want to specialise $G_2$ to give a new $G_3$, which is:

$$G_3=\{<sun, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?>, <?, warm, ?, ?, ?, ?>, <?, ?, ?, ?, ?, same>\}$$

**My problem**

Now, I can definitely appreciate that all elements of $G_3$ are less general than those in $G_2$, but I am struggling to understand why the other 3 possibilities aren't included in $G_3$. The book offers the following explanation:

> Given that there are six attributes that could be specified to
>   specialize $G_2$, why are there only three new hypotheses in $G_3$? For
>   example, the hypothesis $h = (?, ?, Normal, ?, ?, ?)$ is a minimal
>   specialization of $G_2$ that correctly labels the new example as a
>   negative example, but it is not included in $G_3$. The reason this
>   hypothesis is excluded is that it is inconsistent with the previously
>   encountered positive examples. The algorithm determines this simply by
>   noting that $h$ is not more general than the current specific boundary,
>   $S_2$.

I don't understand "$h$ is not more general than the current specific boundary". How is $h=<?, ?, ?, strong, ?, ?>$ not more general than $h=<sun, warm, ?, strong, warm, same>$, but $h=<sun, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?>$ is more general? This seems to me like two of the exact same situation.

Answer (score 1):

When the third input is entered, including h = (sun,?,?,?,?,?) without including h = (?,?,?, Strong,?,?) is a separate matter from general.

This is determined by whether or not it is consistent for the third input.

The h in the existing G is consistent hypothesis for positive input.

However, since the third input is a negative input, the h contained in G must be inconsistent to the input.

That is, G is updated with a set of hypothesis that does not satisfy the third input.

First, since G2 = (?,?,?,?,?,?), G3 is updated from G2 with only one step specific (only one ? is replaced by value).

Also, because the third input, x3 = (rain, cold, high, strong, warm, change), the hypothesis candidates that can be included in G3 are:

```
(sunny (not rain),?,?,?,?,?)

(cloudy (not rain),?,?,?,?,?)

(?, warm,?,?,?,?)

...

(?,?,?, weak (not strong),?,?)

...

(?,?,?,?,?, same)
```

Now we have to choose the hypothesis that can actually be included in the G3 among these hypothesis candidates.

The hypothesis that can be included in G3 is a more general version of S2.

Therefore, only the following list of hypothesis satisfying S2 = (sunny, warm,?, Strong, warm, same) can be included in G3.

```
(sunny,?,?,?,?,?)

(?, warm,?,?,?,?)

(?,?,?,?,?, same)
```

I have uploaded more details about the candidate elimination learning algorithm on my github homepage.

https://github.com/pod3275/Concept-Learning-Candidate-Elimination

Answer (score 0):

I think the question should have been,

```
"why h=<?,?,high,?,?,?> is not more general than h=<sun,warm,?,strong,warm,same> ?"
```

Because, you have to look at only the attribute (Humidity) rather than the complete hypothesis. The constraint "high" is not more general than constraint "?".

Hence we can say *h* is not more general than *S2* and we don't include it.

Please correct me if I am wrong.