# How to determine the general boundary in candidate elimination algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning

I am learning the Candidate-Elimination algorithm by reading [Tom M. Mitchell. Machine Learning (free)](http://profsite.um.ac.ir/~monsefi/machine-learning/pdf/Machine-Learning-Tom-Mitchell.pdf)

TABLE 2.1 in that book gives this set of training examples

[image]

based on this dataset figure 2.3 in that book gives the general boundary G and the specific boundary S.

[image]

I understood the whole thing except **the general boundary** part. why the general boundary is represented as $G_3=\{<Sunny, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?>, <?, Warm, ?, ?, ?, ?>\}$ rather than $G_3=\{<Sunny, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?>, <?, Warm, ?, ?, ?, ?>, <?, ?, ?, Strong, ?, ?>\}$?

Note: this question is different to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/336040/250190), which is discussing $G_3$ rather than G.